# Como lançar erros da controller e capturá-los em uma requisição Ajax - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou usando o AJAX para fazer uma requisição e o retorno é um PartialViewResult. Na requisição, estou passando o model pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel e preciso validá-lo de forma que toda vez que na controller ele chegar NULL, o sistema me retorne uma mensagem de erro e eu possa capturá-la com o ajax e mostrar para o usuário.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/change-forma-contato")]
public PartialViewResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel)
{
    if (pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel == null)
    {
        Return //Retorne o erro: Falha ao realizar a requisição no servidor.
    }

    ViewBag.indice_new = pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel.RowIndice;
    return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaFormaContato/_PessoaFormaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaFormaContatoAppService.ChangePessoaContato(pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel));
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/change-forma-contato",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {

        $this.closest(".row").replaceWith(data);
        set_plugins_pessoa_forma_contato_run_time(rowIndice);
        stopLoadModalInside();

    },
    error: function () {
        stopLoadModalInside();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Você só quer retornar uma mensagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca uma string dentro do if neste ponto:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/change-forma-contato")]
public PartialViewResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel)
{
    if (pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel == null)
    {
        Return 'Falha ao realização requisição'; //Retorne o erro
    }

    ViewBag.indice_new = pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel.RowIndice;
    return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaFormaContato/_PessoaFormaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaFormaContatoAppService.ChangePessoaContato(pessoaFormaContatoParametrosChangeViewModel));
}
```

No Ajax você vai resgatar a informação que vem através da variavel data.

```
error: function (data) {
        stopLoadModalInside();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado." + data);
    }
```

Comment: É bem provável que eu precise exibir mais que uma mensagem. Eu tratei apenas o caso do Model ser null, mas há sim, a possibilidade de ser várias mensagens rsrsrs.

Comment: Exato. se esse for o caso, vai salvando as mensagens em uma variável e depois retorna tudo de uma vez.

Comment: E para pegar essa mensagem com o AJAX, eu preciso vailidar o retorno no bloco: error: function () {
        stopLoadModalInside();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }  ?

Comment: Vou escrever a resposta

Comment: Obrigado @Glenys Mitchell !!